# Need help for Layouts in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: layout, sencha-touch-2

everyone!

I need this layout position for my application in Sencha Touch 2.

[image: Layout position needed]

Code with xtype: 'panel' working correctly

```
items: [
            {
                xtype:        'panel',
                docked:        'left',
                items:    [
                    {
                        xtype:    'panel',
                        docked:    'top',
                        html:    '1'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:    'panel',
                        docked:    'top',
                        html:    '2'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype:        'panel',
                docked:        'top',
                html:        '3'
            }
        ]
```

But if I replace one panel to xtype: 'list'

```
items: [
            {
                xtype:        'panel',
                docked:        'left',
                items:    [
                    {
                        xtype:    'panel',
                        docked:    'top',
                        html:    '1'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:    'list',
                        docked:    'top',
                        store:    'mystore',
                        itemTpl:'<div>{Caption}</div>'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype:        'panel',
                docked:        'top',
                html:        '3'
            }
        ]
```

it not show in browser, only panels with xtype: 'panel' are shown. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try absolute position

```
               {
                    xtype:    'list',
                    docked:    'top',
                    top:    0,
                    bottom:    0,
                    left:    0,
                    right:    0,
                    store:    'mystore',
                    itemTpl:'<div>{Caption}</div>'
                }
```

Agree, it is one of unpleasant quirks of Touch 2.

Cheers, Oleg